# How to convert object to list with keys

Tags: java, list, hashmap

I have a list in the following format

```
[{name=test1, id=something, row=1},
{name=test3, id=something, row=3},
{name=test2, id=something, row=2},
{name=test4, id=something, row=4}]
```

How can I find values according its keys, e.g. I need name from row 3... and also how can I sort it according row

Comment: It looks like JSON (although not valid but I assume real data are valid JSON). In that case all you need is to *parse*/*deserialize* it to probably something like `List<YourClass>` where `YourClass` can hold all above properties. Then you can pick from that list elements at specific indexes, or sort it the way you want.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried? And what is the actual format of this string data? This looks like `toString()` called on a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your example is no valid json I assume that this should just represent the strucutre of the objects. So for a list with object of this class

```
public class NamedRow {
    private String name;
    private String id;
    private int row;

    public int getRow() {
        return row;
    }

    // Other getters + setters
}
```

You can solve this with java streams:

- Assuming the value of row is unique:

```
// return null if not found
public static NamedRow findSingle(List<NamedRow> list, int row){
        return list.stream()
                .filter(namedRow -> namedRow.getRow() == row)
                .findAny()
                .orElse(null);
    }
```

- Assuming the value of row is *not* unique:

```
// returns empty list if no entry matches
public static List<NamedRow> findMultiple(List<NamedRow> list, int row){
        return list.stream()
                .filter(namedRow -> namedRow.getRow() == row)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

Comment: When answering questions like this I find it useful to use a `record` to describe the data structure.  If you aren't familiar with it, it is just like a class but immutable.  And all the `getters`, `constructor`, and `toString` are defined for you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that would assume a Java version of 14+ and could be more confusing for beginners than using `class`, in my opinion.

Comment: Now that java 17 LTS is available, we should promote the new things.  Records are a God send.